Editing staging ground questions is quite inconvenient
When editing staging-ground questions I noticed that the editor appears in a sub window, which makes it quite inconvenient to propose edits.
Not only it's hard to keep track of the current cursor position, but also you don't see a reasonable preview of your edits.
Related: Markdown preview and snippet editor not appearing when editing question

Changed for [tag:Support], according the accepted answer at least the usual markdown preview is already available..Handling could be better though.

There's a mode toggle to have "Markdown with preview mode" at the top right of the editor.
The editor not being inline for people with full edit privs is another matter, but comments are still in the separate editor page, so I don't see much issue.
What I do take issue with is that if I have a pending comment and then go to the edit page, the comment is lost and there's no warning, and it's not carried over. I brought this up during SG beta and it got assigned a ticket (CREATE-489). Maybe it's been forgotten about... In that beta SOfT Q&A, Yaakov commented:

Our preference would be to have an "are you sure" confirmation before leaving the page when there is an unsent comment. Slightly concerned that it will be annoying, but I guess that that is the point, and better not to lose it.

